# Is the ACA nickname capitalized “Obamacare” or “ObamaCare” or “Obama Care”?

Tags: capitalization

I’m writing a term paper and need to know the appropriate acceptable case for “Obamacare”; preferably, I’d refer to it as “The Affordable Care Act”, but the subject of the paper warrants the nickname. I’ve seen articles referring to it as “Obamacare”, “ObamaCare”, “Obama Care” and “Obama care”.

For now, I'm going with “Obamacare”.  Had there been a *[Legal Questions Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44823/legal-questions)*, I’d have asked this there instead.

Comment: Checking out on Google shows that all three are used. Just type "Obamacare" into a Google search window, check out the 19 million hits, choose the one the occurs most often.

Comment: It's an informal title, and as such there is no agreed upon spelling/captialization. (Personally I think "ObamaCare" looks best, it's entirely up to you.)

Comment: Since its usage is at its infancy, you get to vote by choosing one of them to use in your consistency and the term with the most usage would win.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt - Sorry, I am only a fan of using camel case when programming.  I'm sticking with Obamacare, per below.

Comment: @JoshDM Why are you sorry...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the [Washington Post](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3awashingtonpost.com%20obamacare) as well as [The New York Times](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3anytimes.com%20obamacare) appear to consistently prefer *Obamacare*, which as portmanteaux go, is as it should be. Some seemingly exceptional constructions which use mixed-case—such as *WikiLeaks*—are often structured so due to trademark issues or simply because [that is how](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WikiLeaks) they are typed [at the source](http://wikileaks.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Obamacare is the most widely used. But ObamaCare is also used in captions on TV and in newspapers as is Obamascare.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "Obamascare" is a play on "Obama Scare"; the politics surrounding the ACA are not the intention of this question, only determining the most generally accepted or proper capitalization technique.